# In Rails, what is the equivalent of hash() PHP?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

In PHP there are hash() function that accept 'sha256' and string as arguments

Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Example:

```
  $token = hash('sha256', $str);
```

I tried to find an equivalent function in rails but I can only find the
`OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, content)`  that need a `key` to hash.

Is there any function like  `$token = hash('sha256', $str);` in Rails that dont need the key ?

Comment: HMAC is a keyed hash, equivalent to `hash_hmac()` in PHP, not a plain `hash()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can try this way

[ref](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html)

```rb
require 'digest'

# Compute a complete digest
Digest::SHA256.digest 'message'       #=> "\xABS\n\x13\xE4Y..."

sha256 = Digest::SHA256.new
sha256.digest 'message'               #=> "\xABS\n\x13\xE4Y..."

# Other encoding formats
Digest::SHA256.hexdigest 'message'    #=> "ab530a13e459..."
Digest::SHA256.base64digest 'message' #=> "q1MKE+RZFJgr..."
```